# selection of different DB in save( ) django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am making a django app to upload forms. I know I am not doing it in a standard way but still it works. My issue is related to multiple databases. I have defined 3 databases in setting.py as follow:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'testing',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    },

    'Firewall': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'Firewall_Policies',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'testing',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    },

    'CES': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'CES_Policies',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'testing',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

The model of the required class looks like this:

```
class ID_Table(models.Model):
    FQDN = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_column="FQDN")
    CES_Using = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_column="CES_Using")
    MSISDN=models.CharField(max_length=16, db_column="MSISDN")
    IPv4 = models.CharField(max_length=16, db_column="IPv4")
    Unique_ID = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_column="Unique_ID")
    Subscription = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_column="Subscription")
    class Meta:
        db_table='ID_Table'
```

And forms.py file is as:

```
class ID_TableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ID_Table
        fields = ['FQDN', 'CES_Using', 'MSISDN', 'IPv4', 'Unique_ID', 'Subscription']
```

And the views.py file is something like this:

```
def add_table_page(request, table_specified):
    request.session.set_expiry(2000)
    if request.session.get('user_auth') == 'yes':
        if request.method=="POST" and table_specified=='ID_Table.html':
            img = ID_TableForm(request.POST, request.FILES)     
            img.FQDN = request.POST['FQDN']
            img.CES_Using = request.POST['CES_Using']
            img.MSISDN = request.POST['MSISDN']
            img.IPv4 = request.POST['IPv4']
            img.Unique_ID = request.POST['Unique_ID']
            img.Subscription = request.POST['Subscription']

            img.save(using='Firewall')
        return render(request, table_specified)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../login')
```

Now my issue is that I can't select the USING command in save() function. It gives me the following error:

> save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'

Whereas if I remove the word of using and create a table with same name in default database it successfully inserts the data. I want to store the information in a table which is not in the default database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a form instance whose `save` method takes no `using` parameter. You should pass the `using` parameter to the `save` method of a model instance:

```
img_inst = img.save(commit=False)
img_inst.save(using='Firewall')
```

Comment: Thankyou Soo much Moses... I am grateful. It worked perfectly :)